# Java: Transparent TextArea + draw background

Tags: java, swing, applet, transparent, jtextarea

My question here is fairly simple. Can JTextArea's be set to transparent, but not completely invisible? Also, if it's possible, how can I draw an image behind it (draw the image first, and then draw the transparent text area overtop of it)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Override the paintComponent() method of the JTextArea something like:

```
g.drawImage(...);
super.paintComponent(g);
```

2) When you create the text area you will need to give it a transparent background:

```
setBackground( new Color(r, g, b, alpha) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
jScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
jScrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
jScrollPane.setBorder(null);
jScrollPane.setViewportBorder(null);

jTextArea.setBorder(null);
jTextArea.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

jscrollpane is the immediate parent component of the jtextarea.